# Unit test gameobjects on scene

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

I'm having troubles trying to do unit tests. I have a method adding gameobjects on scene, each gameobject has a different position and rotation and a parent. I want to run tests to check my objects are added to their parent with the same position and rotation.

I tried in playmode tests but I keep getting NullReferenceException when doing GameObject.Find() I did the same test in edit mode, but it doesn't work because all objects are not initialized.

How can I test gameobjects on scene when awake and start monobehaviours method have been called ?

I hope someone can help me

Comment: `Find` in general is kind of shitty ... could you add more details like the code you are using etc?

Comment: Generally - try and abstract as much logic away from the Unity framework as possible. Unit test that logic in isolation. Consider anything that interacts with Unity APIs as integration testing.

Comment: Building on Ant P's comment, I highly recommend [the humble object pattern](https://ieftimov.com/post/tdd-humble-object/) if you want your unity code to be unit-testable.

Comment: You need to show the code of the method under test.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reference each object spawned and store them in an array.

After that, you can iterate over the array to test it.

`Gameobject.Find(...)` is costly and can become a problem if want to rename your object in your scene without breaking the script.